# android.support.library. не могу подключить

Tags: android-studio

android.support.library.
Ни через Gradle, ни через настройки она не подключается. В SDK, как везде советуют, Extras раздела вообще нет, как и самой библиотеки.

Библиотека нужны для создания слайдера (перелистывания). Я знаю что она вроде как устарела. Может есть другие библиотеки, или возможности её загрузить.

Просто скачать в интернете - пока даже не искал, мне кажется это не так делается всё таки.

Comment: Лида устарела, да. Надо использовать androidx. Подключать через gradle. Перелистывание - это ViewPager?

Comment: Да ViewPager. Я так понимаю на androidx есть все нужные мне аналоги вьюшек.

Comment: Да, все верно. Просто используйте androidx